# Kotlin, how can I make my code shorter in this spaghetti code?

Tags: kotlin

I'm working on readlines now and can I make this few if's shorter? I'm making a validation to what user is sending to me. The filed cant be empty or null. I have 3 important things that user has to write in field and every three times I have to check the same... .

```
fun readlinesToAddEntryAndValidation(): List<String> {
    println(ENTER_DESCRIPTION_ID_TEKST)
    val entryId: String? = readLine()
    if (!entryId.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        println(ENTER_DESCRIPTION_NAME_TEKST)
        val name: String? = readLine()
        if (!name.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            println(ENTER_DESCRIPTION_TEKST_TEKST)
            val tekst: String? = readLine()
            if (!tekst.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                return listOf(entryId, name, tekst)
            } else {
                println(EMPTY_READLINE_ERROR)
                return readlinesToAddEntryAndValidation()
            }
        } else {
            println(EMPTY_READLINE_ERROR)
            return readlinesToAddEntryAndValidation()
        }
    } else {
        println(EMPTY_READLINE_ERROR)
        return readlinesToAddEntryAndValidation()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to avoid `cognitive complexity` one of the things is avoid nesting. Also when an if always returns something. An `else` statement is not needed

```
fun readlinesToAddEntryAndValidation(): List<String> {
    println(ENTER_DESCRIPTION_ID_TEKST)
    val entryId: String? = readLine()
    
    if (entryId.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        println(EMPTY_READLINE_ERROR)
        return readlinesToAddEntryAndValidation()
    }
    
    println(ENTER_DESCRIPTION_NAME_TEKST)
    val name: String? = readLine()
    
    if (!name.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        println(ENTER_DESCRIPTION_TEKST_TEKST)
        val tekst: String? = readLine()
        if (!tekst.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            return listOf(entryId, name, tekst)
        }
    }

    println(EMPTY_READLINE_ERROR)
    return readlinesToAddEntryAndValidation()       
}
```

Comment: Thank U. It is what I'm looking fir, and thanks fir a good advice what I should avoid in code

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
fun readlinesToAddEntryAndValidation() : List<String> {
    fun read(message: String): String? {
        println(message)
        val line = readLine()
        return if (line.isNullOrEmpty()) null else line
    }

    read(ENTER_DESCRIPTION_ID_TEKST)?.let { entryId ->
        read(ENTER_DESCRIPTION_NAME_TEKST)?.let { name ->
            read(ENTER_DESCRIPTION_TEKST_TEKST)?.let { tekst ->
                return listOf(entryId, name, tekst)
            }
        }
    }
    println(EMPTY_READLINE_ERROR)
    return readlinesToAddEntryAndValidation()
}
```

I wouldn't normally recommend nesting too much, but I feel like that's fairly readable with only three parameters, and the null checking means it short-circuits as soon as you run into a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Making user to reenter all previous (independent!) values after his mistake in the middle of the input is a bad UI.

If user failed to correctly input some entry, you need to ask him to reenter only this single item (until he eventually do it right):

```
fun read(inputMessage: String, errorMessage: String = EMPTY_READLINE_ERROR): String {
    println(inputMessage)
    var line: String? = readLine()
    while (line.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        println(errorMessage)
        println(inputMessage)
        line = readLine()
    }
    return line
}
```

With this auxilary function, whole program become a single-liner:

```
fun readlinesToAddEntryAndValidation() =
    listOf(
        ENTER_DESCRIPTION_ID_TEKST,
        ENTER_DESCRIPTION_NAME_TEKST,
        ENTER_DESCRIPTION_TEKST_TEKST
    ).map { read(it) }
```